# django static files: add timestamp as a parameter to file name

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

Is it possible with django static files app to add a file timestamp as a get parameter to static files, to prevent caching when file is changed (to get something like `<img src="/static/main.png?123892394</a>`)? 
Thanks!

Comment: You could write your own version of `static` tag or directly patch the current one to append a timestamp to the urls. But I doubt you  ever need to do that, because we should only use `staticfiles` during development period, in which files does not get cached explicitly.

Comment: Take a look [here][1] It seems your answer could be there ;-)

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130555/django-static-files-versioning?rq=1